# Unresolved reference: await. Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I'm trying to get data from Api using Retrofit 2 and coroutines. From my GetRepositoriesUseCase I start coroutine but 'await()' function is an unresolved reference.

ViewModel:

```
fun getRepositoryList()  {
    getRepositoriesUseCase(textLiveData.value.toString(), viewModelScope) { result ->
        result.onSuccess { repositoriesList.value = it }
        result.onFailure { show(it.message.toString()) }
    }
}
```

GetRepositoriesUseCase:

```
class GetRepositoriesUseCase(private val repository: ApiRepository) {

operator fun invoke(
    key: String,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    onResult: (Result<Collection<Repository>>) -> Unit
) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            runCatching { repository.getRepositories(key) }
        }
        onResult(result)
    }
}}
```

ApiRepository (here I get error):

```
class ApiRepository(private val api: GitHubApi) {

fun getRepositories(key: String): Collection<Repository> {
    return api.getRepository(key).await().list
}}
```

Api:

```
interface GitHubApi{

@GET("search/repositories")
fun getRepository(@Query("q") query: String)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a return type of a function in `GitHubApi`. If you want to use a Kotlin Coroutines you should also mark this method as `suspend`. Your api interface should be like below:

```
interface GitHubApi {

@GET("search/repositories")
suspend fun getRepository(@Query("q") query: String): Collection<Repository>

}
```

In repository class you should simply pass a suspend function to a use case like this:

```
class ApiRepository(private val api: GitHubApi) {

suspend fun getRepositories(key: String): Collection<Repository> {
    return api.getRepository(key)
}}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by adding this dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your service APIs as suspending. To that end, make sure you use retrofit 2.6.0 or later, then define your service APIs like this

```
@GET("search/repositories")
suspend fun getRepository(@Query("q") query: String): <Return type here>
```

then call it like this

```
suspend fun getRepositories(key: String): Collection<Repository> {
    return api.getRepository(key).list
}
```