# Unresolved reference: await

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to access realtime database Using `await()` on Task.

```
runBlocking {
    var RTDBTask:Task<DataSnapshot!> =  RTDB.child("users").get()
    var result = RTDBTask.await().result /*red line under await()*/
}
```

error message is

```
Unresolved reference: await
```

I don't know what should I do..

Comment: What is `RTDBdata`? Should it be `RTDBTask` instead?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, it is. Sorry, I edited.but still await() doesn't work.

Comment: Next querstion: what is `Task`? Is this a custom class/interface or is it from the Android API? If the later, look at its documentation to learn how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to build.gradle file in app module solved my problem.
implementation '**org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1**'

**Original Source** : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322336/17817594